# Correct usage of IHttpClientFactory for a .NET Core transient service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

I'm looking into using `IHttpClientFactory` for calling external APIs in my ASP.NET Core app. I've seen a few examples where the client factory is created in the constructor of the service's class. Then the methods of that class call the client factory to generate an instance of `HttpClient` to make HTTP requests. Like the following sample code:

```
public class MyTransientService: IMyService
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public MyTransientService(
        IHttpClientFactory clientFactory
    )
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<MyData> GetData()
    {
        //construct the request
        var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        ...
    }
}
```

If the service is registered as transient in Startup.cs, wouldn't a new instance of `HttpClientFactory` be generated each time that the service is called? A new `HttpClientFactory` per request? So wouldn't the following be a more efficient way to use the factory?

```
public class MyTransientService: IMyService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyTransientService(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<MyData> GetData()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(StaticUtils.AddQueryString(url, props));
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider creating the HttpClient yourself bad practice, on self you have control of how many is created. If `MyTransientService` is transient, you will end up creating a lot of socket connections (one for each instance/request) `HttpClient` is created to be reused.

Take a look at Typed clients: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddHttpClient("hello", c =>
    {
        c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
    })
    .AddTypedClient<MyTransientService>();

    services.AddControllers();
}

public class MyTransientService: IMyService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public MyTransientService(
        HtpClient client
    )
    {
        _client = client;
    }

    public async Task<MyData> GetData()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(StaticUtils.AddQueryString(url, props));
        var response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, but I was not thinking to create the HttpClient myself. I thought that calling services.AddHttpClient() in ConfigureServices registers IHttpClientFactory. So I don't need to necessarily create a typed client. I will have more than one service that need HttpClient, so I don't want to create a typed HttpClient for each one.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HttpClientFactoryForTypedHttpClientInstancesInASPNETCore21.aspx